# Find and replace the uppercase characters

Tags: python, string

i want to find and replace the uppercase characters (as `_upperchar`)  in a string.

Eg:  input: `HeLLo Capital Letters`

output : `_He_L_Lo _Capital _Letters`

I tried like:

```
print "saran"
value = "HeLLo Capital Letters"
for word in value:
        print word
        if word.isupper():
                char = "_"
                value = value.replace(word,char + word)

print value
```

and the output I got is,

```
_He___L___Lo _Capital ___Letters
```

Some one please help me to reduce the extra underscores.

Comment: Given that you `print word` (really a character), clearly you can see what's happening. Altering something while iterating over it is not a smart move - maybe try creating a new, separate string instead?

Comment: You are modifying the string that you are iterating. Use another variable instead of `value` inside the for loop

Comment: Hint: read the docs for `str.replace()`, and consider how many replacements it makes each time you call it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `str.join`, add a `_` before the ch if the ch/letter is uppercase, else just keep the letter/ch as is:

```
s=  "HeLLo Capital Letters"

print("".join(["_" + ch if ch.isupper() else ch for ch in s]))
_He_L_Lo _Capital _Letters
```

You run into issues because you are calling replace on the whole string each time so the repeated L's for example end up with three `_`.

If you add a  `print value,word` at the start of the loop you will see what happens:

```
HeLLo Capital Letters H
_HeLLo Capital Letters e
_HeLLo Capital Letters L
_He_LLo Capital Letters L # second L
_He__LLo Capital Letters o # after replacing twice we now have double _
 ........................
```

Some timings against a regex shows a list comp is the best approach:

```
In [13]: s = s * 50

In [14]: timeit "".join(["_" + ch if ch.isupper() else ch for ch in s])
10000 loops, best of 3: 98.9 µs per loop

In [15]: timeit  r.sub( r'_\1', s)
1000 loops, best of 3: 296 µs per loop
```

Comment: Your solution would probably be even faster if you used a generator expression: try timing `"".join(" " + ch ... )`!

Comment: @mauris, that would actually be slower. Python does two passed over what is passed to join do if you pass a generator python will first build a list

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub)

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'([A-Z])', r'_\1', value)
'_He_L_Lo _Capital _Letters'
```

The issue in your example isn't that you're modifying the string whilst iterating over it. Python will create `iter(value)` at the start of the for loop, and changes to `value` after this wont effect the loop due to strings being immutable. The problem is `value.replace` will replace all occurrences in the string, and as there are 3 capital Ls for example, each L will get 3 underscores (`value.replace('L', '_L')` happens 3 times).

Comment: IMO this solution's *intention* is much clearer than Padraic's; this sort of text substitution is the reason the abstraction of regexes exists, so there's no reason to use a confusing list comprehension!

Comment: @Mauris, so you are saying a regex is much clearer than a list comp?

Comment: @Mauris Padraic's list comp based solution is only "confusing" if you don't understand list comps and the `re.sub()` based one only "clearer" if you're familar with regexps.

Comment: I would say it's *a tool more fit for the job*. In general regexes are more of a pain to read, sure, but they abstract away the ugly `for`s and `if`s, and `([A-Z])` → `_\1` is extremely simple as far as they go. So for one, they're worth learning how to use, *and* this is a perfect, entry-level example of how they can be used to solve a problem effectively.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers, regex is almost a language in itself, if you know python at all you should know what a list comprehension is, you could write python forever without knowing what a regex is.

Comment: @Mauris,  are you actually saying the regex is more efficient?

Comment: @Mauris: It's only clearer when you're familiar & comfortable with regex syntax. IMHO, any seasoned Python coder should be comfortable reading & writing single-loop list comprehensions & generator expressions, since they are a standard Python idiom. True, they can get confusing when they contain multiple loops, but Padraic's list comp is fairly straight-forward, and no harder to read than the regex. And I wouldn't be surprised if it was significantly faster than the regex.

Comment: I agree with everything you've written: the list comprehension solution is easy to follow and faster! I just feel like a regex is a more *natural* solution to the problem, because it's more high-level: you're directly translating the *intention* (I want to change each uppercase letter to an underscore followed by that uppercase letter) to a *domain-specific language construct* that says precisely that (`([A-Z])` to `_\1`) and nothing more. *If you know regexes*, you can tell what this does much faster than a loop that does the same thing. *If you don't*, you should learn them, they're useful!

Comment: Regex syntax has often been criticized as a "write-only" language. Sure, if you use them frequently, eventually they become second nature. Still, such dense syntax tends to slow one down when reading code. I've been using regexes for years in various languages, long before I learned Python, but even so, I generally find an equivalent list comp using built-in `str` methods easier to read. And in my timing tests they tend to be more efficient than regexes.

Comment: Of course, there are situations where a regex-baased solution is clearly superior to using `str` methods, and I don't hesitate to use a regex when it's the right tool for the job.

Comment: *IMO* is the key word in my first comment. I know regular expressions are a huge can of worms, and I do agree that they're unnecessarily confusing and ugly (maybe even un-Pythonic!); it just so happens that this is a perfect place to *apply* them. I'm done arguing about this -- use the upvote/downvote arrows to agree/disagree with the approach this solution takes.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Sorry but I don't get your point.  Oh and yes while we're at it: I do know what regexps are, thanks ;)

Comment: (On the *un-Pythonic* bit: I really hope at some point in the future someone comes along and replaces regular expressions with something less awkward to read, the way Python did with its cool new `str.format` method! Are there any such (equally powerful) replacements out there?)

Comment: @bruno.I never said you didn't. My point is you don't have to know anything about re to know python but a there is a pretty good chance if someone is using python that they know what a list comp is.

Comment: @Mauris: Although a clearer form of regex would be nice, it's probably too late to create a new regex-like language. Python's "dialect" of regex is pretty good: you can have non-syntactic whitespace & comments; named groups; meaningful flag names to supplement the cryptic flag letters; and like many modern regex implementations it allows you to use a function as the replacement arg in `re.sub`, which is a feature I really miss in awk. :)

Comment: Yeah, that's super nice. (Now all Python needs is a less awful lambda syntax... ^^)

Answer (score 1):

Look closely what's happening as your code is executed. I've added some "print" statements that show what's going on:

```
Replacing 'H' with '_H':
    _HeLLo Capital Letters

Replacing 'L' with '_L':
    _He_L_Lo Capital _Letters

Replacing 'L' with '_L':
    _He__L__Lo Capital __Letters

Replacing 'C' with '_C':
    _He__L__Lo _Capital __Letters

Replacing 'L' with '_L':
    _He___L___Lo _Capital ___Letters
```

You run into multiple `L` characters, and perform the replacement `L` → `_L` for each of them, so you get:

`L` → `_L` → `__L` → `___L` → ...

The other solutions here apply the replacement (`L` → `_L`) on a *character* level, instead of on the whole string; that's why they work while yours doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your snippet is that when the first time you change H to _H, the next time you iterate, it considers H again because now it is in the second spot ! hence instead of replacing, just create a new string.

```
value = "HeLLo Capital Letters"
new_value = ""
for word in value:
        #print(word)
        if word.isupper():
                char = "_"
                new_value += char + word
        else:
            new_value += word

print(new_value)
```

if an uppercase char is encountered, first condition is executed otherwise the lowercase char is simply appended

Answer (score 0):

```
print "saran"
value = "HeLLo Capital Letters"
print ''.join(['_'+ x if x.isupper() else x for x in value])
```

Comment: Maybe you got the downvotes  because your answer is a dupe of the code Padraic posted 2 minutes earlier. FWIW, I don't think that's fair, since you were probably both composing your answers at the same time, but it happens. Or maybe you got the dv's because you posted code with no explanation.

Answer (score -1):

```
value = "HELLO Capital Letters"         
for word in value:                      
    str = ""                            
    if word.isupper():                  
        val = word                      
    output=word.replace(val, "_"+word)  
    str = str + output                  
    print str
```

Comment: 1) Please put **all** code samples into code blocks. Also, code-only answers are considered inferior here - you should post some explanation with your code. 2) Don't use `str` as a variable name because that shadows the built-in `str` type. 3) This code doesn't function correctly. It prints its output over multiple lines instead of on one line, and it crashes if `value` doesn't begin with an uppercase letter.

Comment: @Vignesh Kalai : thanks... will keep ur advice in mind

Comment: @AkritiAgarwal like wise don't use `str ` as variable name since it will shallow the `string` function